# Does Flying Saucer library support for Google App-Engine?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, flying-saucer

I am trying to create PDF from HTML file in my application . 
  My Entire Application is working on Google App-Engine(GAE) for java.
  Does Flying Saucer library support for GAE?

Please send me solution, if anybody know it.

Answer (score 2):

**Java7**

Flying Saucer uses Abstract Window Toolkit (java.awt.*) which is restricted in [AppEngine Java 7 Runtime Environment](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/runtime). Attempting to use Flying Source gives:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.xhtmlrenderer.pdf.ITextOutputDevice
    at org.xhtmlrenderer.pdf.ITextRenderer.<init>(ITextRenderer.java:102)
    at org.xhtmlrenderer.pdf.ITextRenderer.<init>(ITextRenderer.java:98)
```

However, Flying Sourcer is usable in AppEngine flexible environment.

**Java8**
In [AppEngine Java 8 Runtime Evnvironment](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/runtime-java8), Flying Saucer works like a charm.

Answer (score -2):

What Flying Saucer needs is a well formed XML (in this case, your html) to create the pdf export file.
Since GAE supports servlets

https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/#Java_Requests_and_servlets

Might not be dificult to include the flying Saucer engine within a servlet. Something like this

```
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

public class MyFSServlet extends HttpServlet {
    @Override
    public void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp)
            throws IOException {
        try {
    StringBuffer buf = new StringBuffer();
    buf.append("<html YOUR HTML CODE HERE>"); //could be retrieve from somewhere else
    DocumentBuilder builder = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance().newDocumentBuilder();
    Document doc = builder.parse(new StringBufferInputStream(buf.toString()));
    ITextRenderer renderer = new ITextRenderer();
    renderer.setDocument(doc, null);
    renderer.layout();
    OutputStream os = resp.getOutputStream();
    renderer.createPDF(os);
    os.close();
} catch (Exception ex) {
    ex.printStackTrace();
}
    }
```

}